# Navbar with flex boxes. "Login" positioned right is cut off by overflow

Tags: html, css, flexbox, navbar

Here is my navbar. I use display: flex to get padding around the a links. However, it causes if you see on JSfiddle (zoom out): https://jsfiddle.net/Bradley_/3bhroby2/3/

My "Login" to be cut off slightly especially when you zoom in or when there is overflow. Is there anyway around this? so that it is still positioned right indented slightly. Thanks for any help.

CSS:

body {

```
  margin: 0;
  overflow: visible;
}

#navbar {
  overflow: hidden;
    background-color: #D50000;
    padding:13px 20px;
      display: flex;
    justify-content: flex-start;

}

#navbar a {
        font-family: 'Exo', sans-serif;
    font-size: 15px;
    float: left;

    color: #f2f2f2;
    font-size: 15px;
    padding:13px 20px;
    text-decoration: none;

}

#navbar a:hover {
  background-color: rgba(0,0,0, 0.03);
  color: black;

}

#navbar a.active {
  background-color: #e60000;
  color: white;
}

.content {
  padding: 16px;
}

.sticky {
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  width: 100%
}

.sticky + .content {
  padding-top: 70px;
}

.right {
  margin-left: auto;
}
```

HTML:

```
    <div id="navbar" class="sticky">
    <a class="active" href="index.php">Home</a>
        <a href='matchday.php'>Matchday</a>
        <a href='news.php'>News</a>
        <a href='stats.php'>Stats</a>
        <a href='gallery.php'>Gallery</a>
        <a href='forum.php'>Forum</a>
    <a href='more.php'>More...</a>
        <?php if( isset($_SESSION['username']) && !empty($_SESSION['username']) )
{
?>

        <a style="float:right;" class="open profile dropbtn" href="profile.php"></a>




<?php }else{ ?>
              <a class="right" href="#about">Sign Up </a>
              <a href="#about">Login</a>


<?php } ?>
```

Comment: Add the box-sizing rule? https://jsfiddle.net/sol_b/epdz88ey/ -- You'll need to add some media queries for smaller screens too

Comment: Perfect! You legend! Make it an answer and i can mark it off! Thank you very much!

Comment: Yes ive been trying that, using a drop down however my query puts them all in a list at once but i want to do one at a time as the screen gets smaller. I just dont know how to do that

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/Bradley_/3bhroby2/4/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `padding` on `#navbar` is being added to the `width`, which is causing it to overflow the viewport. Add the `box-sizing` rule to prevent this... [more info here](https://www.paulirish.com/2012/box-sizing-border-box-ftw/)

[updated fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/sol_b/epdz88ey/1/)

```css
html {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

*,
*:before,
*:after {
  box-sizing: inherit;
}

body {
  margin: 0;
  overflow: visible;
}

#navbar {
  overflow: hidden;
  background-color: #D50000;
  padding: 13px 20px;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: flex-start;
}

#navbar a {
  font-family: 'Exo', sans-serif;
  font-size: 15px;
  float: left;
  color: #f2f2f2;
  font-size: 15px;
  padding: 13px 20px;
  text-decoration: none;
}

#navbar a:hover {
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.03);
  color: black;
}

#navbar a.active {
  background-color: #e60000;
  color: white;
}

.content {
  padding: 16px;
}

.sticky {
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  width: 100%
}

.sticky+.content {
  padding-top: 70px;
}

.right {
  margin-left: auto;
}
```

```html
<div id="navbar" class="sticky">
  <a class="active" href="index.php">Home</a>
  <a href='matchday.php'>Matchday</a>
  <a href='news.php'>News</a>
  <a href='stats.php'>Stats</a>
  <a href='gallery.php'>Gallery</a>
  <a href='forum.php'>Forum</a>
  <a href='more.php'>More...</a>
  <a style="float:right;" class="open profile dropbtn" href="profile.php"></a>
  <a class="right" href="#about">Sign Up </a>
  <a href="#about">Login</a>
</div>
```

Comment: jsfiddle.net/Bradley_/3bhroby2/4 - here is my media query if youre willing to have a look at that for me. Rather than lose all in one go id like to lose 1 at a time